# To replace a dummy image in Listview Blackberry10

Tags: listview, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Please help me with this.

I have created a ListView in QML file and filled it with data received from a webservice.Since this web service does not provide any images, i have to place a dummy image in that place. Then i used another method to fetch the images from the url.Now i got the image in my cpp file.But i couldn't update my listview. I have tried out many methods.But failed.
Here is my code snippet.

```
      ListView {
            id: listView
            objectName: "listView"

            dataModel: ArrayDataModel {
                id: myListModel

            }


            // Override default GroupDataModel::itemType() behaviour, which is to return item type "header"
            listItemComponents: ListItemComponent {
                id: listcomponent
                // StandardListItem is a convivience component for lists with default cascades look and feel
                StandardListItem {
                    id: stdlst
                    title: ListItemData.postText
                    description: ListItemData.postDate
                    status: ListItemData.filePath
                    imageSource: assets:///image.png
                }

            }
            layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                spaceQuota: 1.0
            }
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill

        }
```

I need to replace the imagSource in this listview with other image.How can i do it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is: instead of affecting `assets:///image.png` to your `StandardListItem`, you should affect a property of `ListItemData`, which you initialize by default to `assets:///image.png`. Once done, when you fetch your image, you just have to modify the property on your data item.

Let's say your displayed class is called `DataElement`:

```cpp
    class DataElement: public QObject {

        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY(QString postText READ getPostText CONSTANT);
        Q_PROPERTY(QVariant image READ getImage WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged);
        // Other properties here...

    public:
        DataElement() {
            _postText = "Default text";
            _image = QVariant::fromValue
                (bb::cascades::Image(QUrl("file://" + QDir::homePath() + "/image.png")));
        }

        QVariant image() const {
            return _image;
        }

        void setImage(QVariant image) {
            if (image != _image) {
                _image = image;
                emit imageChanged();
            }
        }

        // Missing methods for other properties etc

    signals:
        void imageChanged();

    private:
        QString     _postText;
        QVariant    _image;
    };
```

Your `ListItem` will look like this:

```js
    StandardListItem {
        id: stdlst
        title: ListItemData.postText
        description: ListItemData.postDate
        status: ListItemData.filePath
        image: ListItemData.image
    }
```

Now when you load your image, you call `setImage` with it on your `DataElement`, and the view will be refreshed accordingly.

Comment: In the above code i am filling the postText,postDate and filePath from  a webservice call.But since this webservice does not provide any image,i just put a dummy image in this position.I am only able to get the image after calling another webservice. After getting the image QVariant i need to set it in the image section of the StandardListItem. So is it possible to update the image like this..?

Comment: ``StandardListItem`` has also an ``image`` property. You'll need to bind this property to one of your custom ones (like ``postText``, ``postDate`` and ``filePath``). It should be of type ``QVariant``, as you guessed. Before having the result from your second call to the webservice, you'll set your custom property value to your dummy image, then replace it when you receive the real one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Will you please provide a sample code for this...?

Comment: How can i bind the image property to the custom ones...? Please help me...:(